# How do services/platforms uniquely identify users?

Tags: security, authentication, identity

If you log into a platform (Twitch, Blizzard, Steam, Most Crypto exchanges, Most Banks) from a new device you'll typically get an email stating so.

As far as my knowledge goes, the only information you can get on a request is

1. IP address
2. Device Operating system & version
3. Browser type & version

Are these platforms basing their "unique" users off of this information alone and/or am is there more information that can be gathered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security perspective the largest thing is your identity or how you authenticate.  That's king.  The email stating "hey this is a new device" I've seen handled differently from site to site.  Most commonly it's actually browser cache and I see banks specifically use browser cache to store these kinds of tokens.  Otherwise every time your cellphone connected to a new cell tower you'd likely be flagged as different.  They're not necessarily the same as an authentication token, rather it just says hey I've authenticated as this user to this site before.  Since it's generated by the service provider, the service provider knows to trust it, and it's nearly impossible to hack (assuming it's implemented correctly).

From my own experience the operating systems and browser types, that's more record keeping than actionable insights, however you could build a security system that takes into account an IP address from very different geo-locations.  I.e. why is this guy from the US logging in from China.  They just logged in from California 3 hours ago, this is impossible.  I don't believe most sites really go to that extent though.  I do see MFA providers saying "hey there's a login from china, do you want to approve?".  That workflow makes a lot more sense.

The last part of your question is tricky, regarding "unique users."  Most calculate that based off the number of sessions opened (tabs), or in the case of Twitch (since you mentioned them specifically), the number of tabs that are streaming that video in.  These open platforms where anyone without an account can stream the content obviously treat this differently than say Netflix that makes you authenticate and each account has a limited number of sessions that can be open.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, most of the systems like this stores a cookie in your browser when you log (not the session cookie, just a random ID) that is also assiciated to your account in the provider database, so when you came back, you log in, and they check whether you have that cookie set and in case if the ID matches

They you can probably do some more advance stuff with that ID, like base that value from the browser, OS, expire date and so on